# DXA Build with Sources - CommonAssemblyInfo.cs could not be found

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7, dxa-net

I've added the DXA 1.7 sources to an existing project and am getting the following error on Build.  Any ideas?

> Error CS2001  Source file
>   'C:\TridionCode\MyWebsites\Sdl.Web.Common..\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs'
>   could not be
>   found.    Sdl.Web.Common  C:\TridionCode\MyWebsites\Sdl.Web.Common\CSC    1   Active

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you didn't add all the sources in that case, when looking at the VS project file (https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/Sdl.Web.Common/Sdl.Web.Common.csproj) you see a reference to:

```
<Compile Include="..\CommonAssemblyInfo.cs" />
```

Indicating that `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs` is located outside of the `Sdl.Web.Common` folder. You can find the file in question here:

https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/CommonAssemblyInfo.cs

It is nothing more than a shared assembly info for all projects/assemblies in DXA.